# select state of a UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

i have multiple button in a view, each i have set tag value and calling a same function, my problem is that if i select a button , i need to de-select other button state or you can say i have to show only one button selected at a time.

My Code

```
-(IBAction)checkOption:(id)sender
{
    if([sender tag]==100)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
    if([sender tag]==101)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
    [self performSelector:@selector(doHighlight:) withObject:sender afterDelay:0];
}

- (void)doHighlight:(UIButton*)b {
    if ([b isSelected])
    {
        b.selected = NO;
        b.alpha = 0.5;
    } else {
        b.selected = YES;
        b.alpha = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: are the button `IBOutlets` ?

Comment: yes buttons are IBOutlets

Comment: down voter please either answer or don't down vote without reason if you don't know objective-c

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)buttonSelectDeslect:(UIButton*)sender superView:(UIView*)superView  
{
  for (UIButton *button in [superView subviews]) {
     if ([button isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
         if (sender == button) {
            button.selected = YES;
         }else{
            button.selected = NO;
         }
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create an instance of uibutton to store previous selected button. when you select a current button check this instance if not nil then set its selected property to NO, and then make current button as previous button. Hope i answered your question.

Comment: - (void)doHighlight:(UIButton*)b {
    if (prevButton)
    {
        prevButton.selected = NO;
        
    } 
b.selected=yes;
prevButton=b;

}

declare prevButton as UIbutton in your viewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

Similar with Amit's answer, but add alpha change when button selected status changed.

```
 - (void)doHighlight:(UIButton*)clickBtn
        {
            NSArray *subviews = [clickBtn.superView subviews];
            for (UIButton *subBtn in subviews){
                 if ([subBtn isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]){
                       if (clickBtn == subBtn){
                            subBtn.selected = NO;
                            subBtn.alpha = 0.5;
                       } else {
                            subBtn.selected = YES;
                            subBtn.alpha = 1;
                       }
                 }
             }
         }
```